# injecting $http into directive controller and minification

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm getting one of these in my prod environment

```
[$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.2/$injector/unpr?p0=nProvider
```

My directive is something along these lines

```
var app = angular.module('myDir', []);

function link(scope, elm, attrs) {
    scope.$watch('Potato', function (nVal) {
        if (nVal) {
            elm.html(Potato);
        }
     }

function someDir(http, compile) {
    function controller($scope, http) {
        http.get('/some/service/' + $scope.someThing).success(function (result) {
            scope.Potato = result;
            console.log('hooray');
        });
    };

    var dirObject = {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            'someThing': '='
        },
        link: link,
        controller: controller
    };

    return dirObject;
};
app.directive('someDir', ['$http', '$compile', someDir]);
```

Is this how I should be handling injecting `$http` into a directive controller? Solution is hosted on azure, and minified via `ASP.NET MVC` bundles.

If I render all my script files individually instead of letting them get minified, everything works, but when they get minified I get the unknown provider error.

**Adding controller that is running outside of the directive.**

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";

    var profileApp = angular.module('profileApp', ['myDir']);

    function ProfileCtrl(scope) {

        scope.companyId = angular.element("#Id").val();

    };

    profileApp.controller('ProfileCtrl', ['$scope', ProfileCtrl]);

    angular.bootstrap(document, ['profileApp']);

});
```

Comment: That looks right. If you use array notation, the minification works fine. Were you implementing it the same way, when you got this error? Are you sure you are getting this error for the directive?

Comment: same implementation template.  actual code inside the controller of the directive is much longer.  this is my first attempt at a directive with injected $http.

Comment: also, fairly sure it's the directive and not the primary controller on the page.

Comment: Create a demo. It will help. Your directive return nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should return the `dirObject` from `someDir()`. I guess this could be a typo.

Also the controller definition is wrong. Use the array injection, if you want the minified version to run:

```
function controller($scope, http) { ... }

var dirObject = {
    ...
    controller: ["$scope", "$http", controller]
}

return dirObject;
```

Comment: not returning dirObject was a typo.  i will try this method of injection and report back.

Comment: My application works well on production environment. But I get this same error after hosting it online.